# SQL: Give me last entry between dates

Tags: sql

i want to have the last entry where my entry is between dates:

```
    Isin             Date          Price   
______________    ____________    __________

'GB00B1YW4409'    '31.12.1999'    [688.1300]
'GB00B1YW4409'    '03.01.2000'    [688.1300]
'GB00B1YW4409'    '04.01.2000'    [690.6200]
'GB00B1YW4409'    '05.01.2000'    [666.9500]
'GB00B1YW4409'    '06.01.2000'    [650.7600]
'GB00B1YW4409'    '07.01.2000'    [663.2200]
'GB00B1YW4409'    '10.01.2000'    [694.3500]
'GB00B1YW4409'    '11.01.2000'    [683.7700]
'GB00B1YW4409'    '12.01.2000'    [675.0500]
'GB00B1YW4409'    '13.01.2000'    [664.4600]
```

For example i want to have the last price available of (01.Jan 2001 - One Year). But unfortunatly the 1st January is a holiday and thus there aren´t any prices. SO i am looking for the next entry available (3rd January 2000). My first thoughts are something like

```
Select List.Price from List where List.Date ...
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:MATLAB]?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: I first tagged Matlab (which got removed), but because it´s a "normal" query, i thought i don´t have to mention it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  TOP 1 List.Price
FROM
  List
WHERE
  Date >= 01.01.2000
ORDER BY
  Date
```

This should return the Price that matches the date you ask for and if that date is not present in the table, you should get the Price from the next available date.

Comment: Maybe you could help me further. Now i want to join this date with another table. Something like: ... 

join list2 on list1.isin=list2.isin where list2.date= (last entry)

Comment: I would need to see more details of what you want to join to before I could offer suggestions on that.  I see there are many answered questions on StackOverflow about SQL joins and there are many other website tutorials on the subject as well.  If none of those are helpful to you, perhaps you could enter another question with more details about what you are looking for.